# Notation and name for this function?

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, soft-question, notation, terminology

Let $k \geq 1$; let $V,W$ be vector spaces; and let $T: V \to W$ be linear. Then how do we call and denote the function $(v_{1},\cdots, v_{k}) \mapsto (T(v_{1}), \cdots, T(v_{k})): V^{k} \to W^{k}$?

Comment: I don't think a standard notation exists, but I would denote it by $T \oplus \dots \oplus T$.

Comment: Borrowing from the direct sum notation?

Comment: Yes. In some contexts, if $f:A \to B$ and $g: C \to D$ are homomorphisms, one can define the map $f \oplus g : A \oplus C \to B \oplus D$ as $(a,c) \mapsto (f(a),g(c))$. Also $f \times g$ is used.

Comment: Much appreciated. Using $\times$ here has any relation to "multiplication"?

Comment: No, $\times$ is related to cartesian product.

Comment: Ah ah, exactly. Yeah, a wise borrowing.

Comment: I think I may use the Cartesian notation. An intuitive and mnemonic notation. Can you provide some analysis of the pros and cons of each of the two notations? Perhaps you would like to make it an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In some contexts, when direct products are defined (e.g. vector spaces, groups, modules...) given two maps
$$f: A \to B \\ g : C \to D$$ one defines $$f \times g : A \times C \to B \times D$$
as $(a,c) \mapsto (f(a), g(c))$.

Sometimes (when you work with modules or vector spaces) products are denoted with the symbol $\oplus$ and are called direct sums. This is your case: usually such maps are denoted by $f \oplus g$. But this is just a matter of taste.